# Why Roboto kerning doesn't work properly on web?

Tags: website-design, fonts, web-fonts, kerning

I'm trying to fix this problem with Roboto regular kerning, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know where is the problem?

Why font isn't the same as in my Adobe programs?[image]

Comment: Hi Ivana, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please clarify a bit what your problem is? I don't see huge problems with kerning in your screenshot. If you could point out the problems, we might be able to help you better. Thanks! If you have any questions about using this site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Can you check how the title Task category looks like. It seems like letters in task are to close

Comment: Do you have a live example? What version of the font and how are you using it (e.g. Google fonts, your own generated web-font etc.)?

Comment: Please circle or enlarge that part of your image. Even with your comment, it took me a couple seconds to find the word you were pointing out.

Comment: Simply put: Web browsers render things, including letters and letter spacing, differently than operating systems. They're less exact

Comment: It might just be the image, but all of the bold title text looks like it's rendering as Arial Bold. Double check that you have the font importing correctly in your code. If you have a proper font stack set up it might be disregarding Roboto and moving on to the next font (Arial?) in the stack.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot retake my screenshot again but you can see the problem in the first green row. Ok, if that's Arial Bold how my developer can fix it to look like Roboto. Is there some plugin or converter? I used generator from Fontsquirrel, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If this is web related you can use the css property: letter-spacing and set both positive and negative values.

There is also font-kerning but only has three values.